# date_default_timezone_set() for PHP 4.4

Tags: php

Ihave the following code and it works fine on my local host but my website is running PHP 4.4.4 and date_default_timezone_set() is for PHP 5. How do I get this to work for PHP 4?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
$date = getdate();
$year = $date["year"];
$month = $date["mon"];
$time = $date["hours"].':'.$date["minutes"];
```

Comment: You really don't want to work with php4, it's the year 2014 after all...

Comment: Trust me I know. But I dont have much of a choice really.

Comment: Is there any chance at all you can upgrade to PHP5? This is a serious question.

Comment: Seriously! Upgrade! PLEASE! For the love of God! UPGRADE!!!
http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/cvssscoremin-4/cvssscoremax-4.99/PHP-PHP.html